# Can anyone help me fix this coding error that i keep getting

Tags: error-handling

This is my code:

```
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remotes = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Remotes")

local selectChance = require(script:WaitForChild("SelectChance"))
local chanceList = require(script:WaitForChild("ChanceList"))

remotes:WaitForChild("RollFunction").OnServerInvoke = function(player)
    local Table = {}
    
    for i = 1, do
        table.insert(Table, selectChance.getRandomIndex(chanceList))
    end
    
    return Table
end
```

This is the error I get when trying the game:

> ServerScriptService.Main:10: Expected identifier when parsing expression, got 'do'

I can't find a solution anywhere

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: idk its on roblox studio

Comment: If you don't know what language it is then how can you tell that your code is correct in any way?  
However, it is a reasonable assumption that the construct `for i=1, do` does not make sense. In almost all languages a `for` statement is used to iterate a list or numerical progression. So you probably need to give a step and terminal value, something like: `for i = 1 to 10 step 1 do` which would repeat the following block 9 or 10 times, depending on the rules of the language.